# how do I calculate proportions sqrt transformed by row?

Tags: r

My data looks like this. how do I calculate proportions (sqrt transformed) by row (per Id)?
This is a large dataset of over 10 000 records.

```
Id  dogs cats birds fish 
602 1    0     1    1
603 0    1     1    1
603 1    1     1    0
```

Comment: You may need the `apply` function : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/apply

Comment: Can you show me how to use apply ? My dataset is big, more than 10000 records.

Answer (score 3):

Up front, I think something like this:

```r
sqrt(dat[,-1] / rowSums(dat[,-1]))
#          Ap        Ak        Al        Aj
# 1 0.5773503 0.0000000 0.5773503 0.5773503
# 2 0.0000000 0.5773503 0.5773503 0.5773503
# 3 0.5773503 0.5773503 0.5773503 0.0000000
```

Step-through:

```r
dat[,-1]
#   Ap Ak Al Aj
# 1  1  0  1  1
# 2  0  1  1  1
# 3  1  1  1  0

rowSums(dat[,-1])
# [1] 3 3 3

dat[,-1] / rowSums(dat[,-1])
#          Ap        Ak        Al        Aj
# 1 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333
# 2 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
# 3 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000
```

Comment: This gives me an error: 'x' must be numeric
>

Comment: @user17122732 error is clear, check your data columns classes. `str(dat)`

Comment: Up front, please share your *real* data by editing your question and adding the output from `dput(x)` to a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). (It sounds like your matrix or frame is not what you think it is.

Comment: Any updates, @user17122732? If you don't know what your data is, perhaps it's best to first run `dat[,-1] <- lapply(dat[,-1], type.convert, as.is = TRUE)` on your data. After that, all columns that look like numbers should be numbers (except the first, which I intentionally excluded because in my head `Id` is likely to be categorical, not numerical).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("A"), ~sqrt(./sum(c_across(Ap:Aj)))))
```

```
  Id    Ap    Ak    Al    Aj
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   602 0.577 0     0.577 0.577
2   603 0     0.577 0.577 0.577
3   603 0.577 0.577 0.577 0
```

Comment: This didn't work for me because my data is characters.

Comment: you could use `df %>% type.convert(as.is=TRUE) %>% rowwise()...`

Comment: or start your pipeline with `df %>% mutate(across(-Id, as.numeric)) %>% ...`

Comment: I tried this but when I include as.numeric , it returns NAs.